# Confusion about how to write this Linq query

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I have an xml document look like this

```
<Account Id="1">
    <UserName>text</UserName>
    <Password>text</Password>
    <AddingDate>text</AddingDate>
    <AccountType>text</AccountType>
</Account>
```

I am trying to update this document using linq query but linq is very new to me I am trying to write something like this. I am really confused .

```
private void UpdateAccount(string name, string pass, string type, int id)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("UserAccounts");

    var v = from c in doc.Elements("Account").Select(new XElement("UserName", name),
        new XElement("Password", pass),
        new XElement("AddingDate", DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()),
        new XElement("AccountType", type))
///       where (attaribte.value = id) 
    ;
}
```

Comment: We can't guess just by looking at your code what you're trying to do. Be specific.

Comment: "I am confused" is not a proper problem description. Explain what you want to do, what this code is supposed to do, what it actually does and what you have tried to make it do what you want it to.

Comment: @Raul and code Faster Its not difficult to guess what I am trying to do .I have an xml file and update fuction  and an update query as you can see abow   .so guess what genius  ......If you take a look that code  It shoudnt be too diffucult to understand . or mybe you might want to ask  HimBromBeere or Dhru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you´ll need this:

```
var v = from c in doc.Elements("Account")
    .Where(x => x.Element("Id") == yourID)
    .Select(new XElement("UserName", name),
        new XElement("Password", pass),
        new XElement("AddingDate", DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()),
        new XElement("AccountType", type));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this

```
XElement books = XElement.Parse(
           @"<books>
                <book>
                <title>Pro LINQ: Language Integrated Query in C#2010</title>
                <author>Joe Rattz</author>
                </book>
                <book>
                <title>Pro .NET 4.0 Parallel Programming in C#</title>
                <author>Adam Freeman</author>
                </book>
                <book>
                <title>Pro VB 2010 and the .NET 4.0 Platform</title>
                <author>Andrew Troelsen</author>
                </book>
                </books>");

    //XElement Xbooks = XElement.Parse(@"XMLFile.xml");
    var titles =
    from book in books.Elements("book")
    where (string)book.Element("author") == "Joe Rattz"
    select book.Element("title");
    foreach (var title in titles)
        Console.WriteLine(title.Value);
```